# How to compare attributes of a NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsattributedstring

I'm filtering attributed text depending on certain attributes. Is there a way to compare `if ([attrString.attributes isEqualToDictionary:myAttributes])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [-enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/enumerateAttributesInRange%3aoptions%3ausingBlock%3a)

Within the block, you can test whether the attributes of a run are exactly equal to your desired set of attributes using `[attrs isEqualToDictionary:myAttributes]`. Be warned: This will return `NO` if the run contains any attributes you weren't looking for.

If you only want to see whether the attributes in `myAttributes` are set (and compare their values), without rejecting other attributes, use `[[attrs dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[myAttributes allKeys]] isEqualToDictionary:myAttributes]`.

Comment: Within the block, `[attrs isEqualToDictionary:myAttributes]` will work, but will return `NO` if the run contains any attributes not present in `myAttributes`. If you only want to see whether the attributes in `myAttributes` are set, without rejecting other attributes, use `[[attrs dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[myAttributes allKeys]] isEqualToDictionary:myAttributes]`.

Comment: @PeterHosey - it took me long time to see your comment, but better later than never. Please make this into an answer and i shall accept it.

Comment: @user1244109: It was always meant as an extension of Emmanuel's answer, so I edited it in there instead.